# Filter "Multi-Categories" with jQuery-EasyFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to modify [jQuery EasyFilter](https://github.com/RafaelSilva-RFS/jquery.easyfilter): currently, each item has one unique category passed by `data-easyitem` of the item. I'd like to assign multiple categories for one item. For demonstration please take a look at [**this pen**](https://codepen.io/knzone/pen/VwjQymJ).

Item 4 is assigned to Category 1 and Category 4: `data-easyitem="cat1,cat4"`.
So it should show up when I activate *Category 1* and also when I click *Category 4*.

I think I need to `.split` the `data-easyitem` passed by the item and compare it to the category value.

This might be the right place to do it?

```js
$(this.wrap)
    .find("[data-easyitem]")
    .each(function() {
        var item = $(this);

        // Compare if the ['data-easyfilter'] is diferent from *
        if (value !== "*") {
            if (item.attr("data-easyitem") == value) {
                showItems.push(item[0]);
            } else {
                hiddeItems.push(item[0]);
            }
        } else {
            showItems.push(item[0]);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, I really don't know **how**. I would be thankful for any tips and hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the `attr("data-easyitem")` value  and `split` them .Then use `for-loop` to loop through values got after splitting and finally compare these `values` with the category selected depending on this show or hide items.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  "use strict";

  // Default options
  var defaults = {
    firstFilter: "*",
    animation: "slide",
    duration: 400
  };

  // The plugin constructor
  function EasyFilter(element, options) {
    // Merge user settings with default, recursively
    this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

    // Wrap container element
    this.wrap = $(element);

    // Call initial method
    this.init();
  }

  $.extend(EasyFilter.prototype, {
    init: function() {
      var object = this;

      this._addEvents();
      this.filter(object.options.firstFilter);
    },

    filter: function(value) {
      console.clear()
      var object = this;

      var showItems = [];
      var hiddeItems = [];

      $(this.wrap)
        .find("[data-easyitem]")
        .each(function() {
          var item = $(this);
          if (value !== "*") {
            //get attr value and split between `,`
            var items_ = item.attr("data-easyitem").split(",");
            //loop through the splits values
            for (var i = 0; i < items_.length; i++) {
              //check if the value i.e : `(data-easyfilter)` is == to split value
              if (items_[i] == value) {
                showItems.push(item[0]); //show them
              } else {
                hiddeItems.push(item[0]); //hide
              }
            }
          } else {
            showItems.push(item[0]);
          }
        });

      object._toggleItems(hiddeItems, showItems);
    },

    _slideItemsEffect: function(value, showItems) {
      var object = this;
      $(value).slideUp(object.options.duration, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $.each(showItems, function(index, value) {
            $(value).slideDown(object.options.duration, function() {});
          });
        }, 300);
      });
    },

    _fadeItemsEffect: function(value, showItems) {
      var object = this;
      $(value).fadeOut(object.options.duration, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $.each(showItems, function(index, value) {
            $(value).fadeIn(object.options.duration, function() {});
          });
        }, 300);
      });
    },

    _toggleItems: function(hiddeItems, showItems) {
      var object = this;

      // Compare if there is more than one item to hide
      if (hiddeItems.length > 0) {
        // Hide and show item from arrays
        $.each(hiddeItems, function(index, value) {
          switch (object.options.animation) {
            case "slide":
              object._slideItemsEffect(value, showItems);
              break;
            case "fade":
              object._fadeItemsEffect(value, showItems);
              break;
            default:
              object._slideItemsEffect(value, showItems);
          }
        });
      } else {
        //Show all items
        $.each(showItems, function(index, value) {
          switch (object.options.animation) {
            case "slide":
              $(value).slideDown(object.options.duration, function() {});
              break;
            case "fade":
              $(value).fadeIn(object.options.duration, function() {});
              break;
            default:
              $(value).slideDown(object.options.duration, function() {});
          }
        });
      }
    },

    _addEvents: function() {
      var object = this;

      // Click
      $(this.wrap)
        .find("[data-easyfilter]")
        .click(function() {
          object.filter($(this).attr("data-easyfilter"));
        });
    }
  });

  // Easy Filter Wraper
  $.fn.easyFilter = function(options) {
    this.each(function() {
      new EasyFilter(this, options);
    });
  };
})(jQuery, window, document);


$('#easy-filter-wrap').easyFilter();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.5.2/materia/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="jquery-script-menu">

  <div class="container">

    <div id="easy-filter-wrap">

      <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle mb-3" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" data-easyfilter="*">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option0" checked>
          All
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-easyfilter="cat1">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1">
          Category 01
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-easyfilter="cat2">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2">
          Category 02
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-easyfilter="cat3">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3">
          Category 03
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-easyfilter="cat4">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4">
          Category 04
        </label>
      </div>

      <br /><br />
      <!--put both value here as  well-->
      <div data-easyitem="cat1,cat4" class="alert alert-danger">
        Item 01 (Category 1)
      </div>
      <div data-easyitem="cat2" class="alert alert-danger">
        Item 02 (Category 2)
      </div>
      <div data-easyitem="cat3" class="alert alert-danger">
        Item 03 (Category 3)
      </div>
      <div data-easyitem="cat1,cat4" class="alert alert-danger">
        Item 04 (Category 4)
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works like a charm! thanks a lot! updated pen: [link](https://codepen.io/knzone/pen/rNLdVyg)

Comment: I "improved" the demo code a little bit. the code provided by you made items with more than one category first disappear and then show up if category matched. i fixed that (with my limited js skills..) but thanks again! see [link](https://codepen.io/knzone/pen/QWEmVEE)